# Как проверить на существование базу данных при подключении к ней через PDO?

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Как вариант, при подключении к несуществующей базе данных PDO кидает исключение с кодом 1049. Есть другие варианты? И если можно подскажите пожалуйста где можно посмотреть какой код получаемые с метода getCode() экземпляра класса PDOException за какую ошибку отвечает?

Comment: (Мало ли кому пригодиться) Код возвращаемые методом getCode это код которые возвращает сама СУБД, в моем случае это MySQL, то есть смотреть какой код за какую ошибку отвечает нужно смотреть в документаци MySQL. Вот по этой http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html ссылке кода ошибок, но правда четко не описан за что какая отвечает хотя по названию в принципе понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

1. Посылаете запрос на существующие базы на этом сервере
2. Элемент спискаСмотрит есть ли ваша база - то коннектитесь, нет - пишете базы нет